# How to fix ClassCastException in enhanced for-loop?

Tags: java, arraylist, foreach, classcastexception

```
List<Object[]> listOfObjectArray = new ArrayList<Object[]>(); 
// List of object arrays, where each element is an array.

....

listOfObjectArray = ##Somerecords; (Eg : [12.0,13.0,14.0,15.0....])

...

for(Object[] obj : listOfObjectArray) {...}
```

Here if the length of array in the list is 1, I am getting `ClassCastException`. How to fix this?

Comment: what datatype is `listOfObjectArray`? So some more code would be helpful

Comment: Is this listOfObjectArray an List of Arrays?

Comment: Perhaps use `for(Object obj : listOfObjectArray) {...}` instead.

Comment: Please post code for how `listOfObjectArray` is initialized

Comment: Edited question with the listOfObjectArray  initialization.

Comment: Include the *full relevant* exception message. Unless you are losing type information - ie. `SomeRecords()` returns a `List`, and not a `List<Object[]>`, where each item is a double and not the expected Object[] - then the posted code is not a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *only* way the problem can exist *given the posted code*, if the reported exception/line is correct, is when **"Somerecords" is not *really* creating a `List<Object[]>` object** - but a `List` containing *non*-Object[] elements.

One reason could be the method in question is typed to return a *non-generic* `List`, filled with double values. Java will type-accept this *with a warning* - eg. "uses unchecked or unsafe operations".

That is, `C<T> generic = (C)generic_or_plain` is compile-time type-valid - *even if the resulting code is run-time type-invalid*. Similarly, `C plain = (C<T>)compatible_generic_or_plain` is valid code but can result in a misuse of `plain`.

Consider:

```
List<Object[]> r = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
List r2 = r; // Because generics are "imaginary" we can fake this,
             // but the compiler WILL GENERATE A WARNING at type information loss
r2.add(1.2); // Now we add a Double (to r since r2 is r)

// CC! - Have a Double where Object[] was expected
Object[] res = (Object[])r.get(0);
```

Another way this can be caused, with the same issue, but from the different side:

```
// Type-valid, but "unsafe" (and invalid)
List<Object[]> r = (List)Arrays.asList("Hello");

// CCE! - Have String, expected Object[]
Object[] res = (Object[])r.get(0);
```

Solution: *Use generics everywhere and don't ignore or suppress compiler warnings.*

Suggestion: Include the *full* Exception Message in future posts, as it will show the types involved - and likely result in less close/down votes.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the solution. Sorry for not giving proper details in question. You have got my issue.

Comment: Go to the the code that generates "somerecords" and make sure it returns a valid List object containing Object[] elements. Without *showing* the method (or code) to get "somerecords" it is not possible to say why it was generated incorrectly. If generic type information is propagated throughout the entire program then the correctness this will be guaranteed by the type-system itself.

Answer (score 1):

from java docs of [ClassCastException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html)

> Thrown to indicate that the code has attempted to cast an object to a
>   subclass of which it is not an instance

See this example,

```
String[] names = {"Ethan Hawke", "Julie Delpy"}; // Array of String objects
for(Object name : names){ 
   System.out.print("Name: " + (int)name); // casting String object to int
}
```

throws,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot 
be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

**Update:**

You are not casting your `Object[]` data properly,

see this,

```
List<Object[]> listOfObjectArray = new ArrayList<Object[]>();

Object[] intArrary = { 1, 2, 3, 4 }; // declare an int array
Object[] intArrary2 = { 4, 5, 6, 7 }; // declare an int array
Object[] intArrary3 = { 5.0, 5.3, 2.0, 1.8 }; // declare a double array

listOfObjectArray.add(intArrary); // add it in Object array
listOfObjectArray.add(intArrary2); // add it in Object array
listOfObjectArray.add(intArrary3); // add it in Object array

for (Object[] outerArray : listOfObjectArray) {
    for (Object innerArray : outerArray) { // for each array "s" in array "p"

        // check if array type is Integer.
        if (innerArray instanceof Integer)
            System.out.println((int) innerArray); // cast your array to int

        // check if array type is Double.               
        if (innerArray instanceof Double)
            System.out.println((double) innerArray); // cast your array to double
    }
}
```

**Output**,

```
1
2
3
4
4
5
6
7
5.0
5.3
2.0
1.8
```

Comment: List<Object[]> listOfObjectArray = new ArrayList<Object[]>();

is the declaration.. Each element in the list is an array. My syntax is correct.